# Update in fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to execute an UPDATE in a `mysql_fetch_array()` loop? Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM inbox"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())){
echo "<div>";
echo "<form method='POST'>";
echo "<h1>".$row['link']."</h1>";
echo "<h3>".$row['tittle']."</h3> na";
echo "<input type='text' name='tittle'>";
echo "<h3>".$row['content']."</h3>";
echo "<textarea name='content'></textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='".$row['link']."' value='Change'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
$tit = $_POST['tittle'];
$ten = $_POST['content'];
$link = $row['link'];
if (isset($_POST[$link])) { mysql_query("UPDATE inbox SET tittle='$tit' content='$ten' WHERE link='$link'");}
}
```

It have to do update in mysql_fetch_array(), because I wanna to change content of that things.

Comment: What problem are you having

Comment: It does not work... I cry...

Comment: @MatejKolec'ko See the second edit on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax as the values should be `,` delimited:

```
if (isset($_POST[$link])) { 
    mysql_query("
                    UPDATE inbox SET tittle='$tit', 
                         content='$ten' 
                    WHERE link='$link'
                 ");}
```

## Note:

You should [take a look at the mysqli class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to handle your future queries. It's just as simple as your current method, but more secure and *not* deprecated.